Why don't I recover disk space after a btrfs subvolume snapshot deletion?
To save disk space, I have done a btrfs subvolume delete /mnt/snapshots/some_snapshot. The result is I have not recovered any space, controlled with df -h.
This result is very surprising because there are several tens of Gb of differences with the active system (e.g. /var 120Gb vs 2Gb, /opt 44Gb vs 1Gb, /usr 28Gb vs 9Gb). Do I need to perform other actions to recover space like rebooting or some btrfs cleaning command?
Before deleting, here is how it looked:
du -hs /mnt/snapshots/*
9,4G    /mnt/snapshots/v2
9,4G    /mnt/snapshots/v1
194G    /mnt/snapshots/some_snapshot
12K /mnt/snapshots/historique
8,6G    /mnt/snapshots/v0

Any other snapshot is 20 times smaller at least. So my misunderstanding.

(1) "Any other snapshot is 20 times smaller at least" – How about the original subvolume? Is the original subvolume what you call "the active system"? How exactly have you got these "several tens of Gb of differences"? (Do you mean GB? Measuring disk usage in gigabits is very uncommon.) (2) In btrfs prefer sudo btrfs fi du -s /mnt/snapshots/* over du -hs /mnt/snapshots/*. (3) The filesystem needs some time for accounting and such. df -h just after deleting a subvolume may show no gain in available space, you may need to wait a minute or two. (4) Are there other snapshots (elsewhere)?

One of the interesting facts about BtrFS is that free space reclaiming seems to work asynchronously:
When I deleted some files, it took some time until the free space could be seen via df; running it repeatedly for some time showed that the free space increased

When deleting snapshots it can take some time before they are actually deleted in the background and space is freed up.
It is important to keep an eye on the unallocated space and avoid it getting too low, it is checked with "btrfs fi usage" and if the difference between the free and the unallocated space is too much it is necessary to perform the balance.
du can't give you real size on BTRFS, the real size can be lower if compression is used, you can check the compression with compsize command.
Can be most if there is a lot of fragmentation, for example on vm disk files with cow active or other things, especially if they contain cow filesystems (cow on cow is the worst case).
About the snapshot the "real size" is the difference (it can be totally different from du), or more precisely the exclusive space of that snapshot, not used by the subvolume or other snapshots, which is also similar to files copied with reflink.
When snapshot is created its "real size" is 0 but while on the original subvolume you continue to write it grows with the differences.
You also have to be careful with the use of defragmentation which increases space if used on files that have reflink or snapshot copies.
To see the real size and easily identify any "anomalous" space usage in the case of huge fragmentation (which it calls "unreachable") can help btdu.
Important note: to calculate all the space correctly must be used with the top-level subvolume (otherwise btdu will be unable to open other subvolumes for inode resolution).
